# Multiple hosts updating same localhost variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

If in my playbook, a play is being run on multiple hosts, each host updating a localhost variable, what value of localhost variable is stored?

```
- hosts: groupa
  serial: 2
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      deploy: A Random Integer (different for different server)
    when: prev_failure.stat.exists
    delegate_to: localhost
  - debug: msg="{{hostvars['localhost']['deploy']}}"
```

What should I be expecting the behavior of such code?

Should it print the same values or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` is the Ansible controller.

`debug` will print the `deploy` value from the Ansible controller, if it was executed, i.e. if `localhost` is a member of `groupa`.

If `localhost` is not a member of `groupa` an exception will be raised.

Each member of `groupa` will have `deploy` fact set.

---

See the [delegated facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegated-facts) in the docs:

> By default, any fact gathered by a delegated task are assigned to the `inventory_hostname` (the current host) instead of the host which actually produced the facts (the delegated to host).

You can change the behaviour using `delegate_facts: true`.